# SQL Join - WHERE hiding results I need to show

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following tables:

*User*

```
id | full_name | active
1  | joe       | 1
2  | dave      | 0
```

*Cert_Type*

```
id | cert_name
1  | Cert 1
2  | Cert 2
3  | Cert 3
```

*Cert*

```
id | user_id | cert_type_id | expires
1  | 1       | 1            | 2022-10-24
2  | 2       | 2            | 2021-01-10
```

My SQL query:

```
SELECT u.full_name, ct.cert_name, c.expires 
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN Cert 
  ON u.id = c.user_id 
FULL JOIN Cert_Type 
  ON c.cert_type_id = ct.id
WHERE u.active = 1
```

The results I need:

1. Show the *expiry* of a **Cert** associated with a **User**
2. Contain all **Cert Types** even if one isn't associated with a **User**
3. Do not display the *expiry* for a **User** who is not *active*

What I would like my retrieved table to look like:

```
full_name | cert_name | expires
joe       | Cert 1    | 2022-10-24
NULL      | Cert 2    | NULL
NULL      | Cert 3    | NULL
```

What is actually retrieved:

```
full_name | cert_name | expires
joe       | Cert 1    | 2022-10-24
NULL      | Cert 3    | NULL
```

I think the fact that **User** 'dave' is not *active* it's excluding 'Cert 2'.

I'm not sure if I need two separate SELECTs and merge the results?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some `outer join`s and `case` expressions should get the job done:

```
select case when "User".active = 1 then full_name end as full_name,
cert_name,
 case when "User".active = 1 then expires end as expires
from "User" full join Cert
on "User".id = Cert.user_id
full join Cert_type
on Cert.cert_type_id = Cert_type.id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c3c0c8e1ad13fdb8dda0dcc955cb41a)

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt response, I've replicated it in my actual project and had a slight issue; which I think is my fault for missing some information, apologies. I also have a users that are active but don't have an associated certificate. I need these to be displayed too but expiry date will be blank. Fiddle - [link] https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69251b7026b1b39125524f107892bfb7

Comment: @squatman check my edited answer.